# Ошибка Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность

Есть данный код на СИ, суть в том, чтобы в двумерном массиве с помощью потоков (Linux) найти самую большую последовательность чисел по возрастанию. При компиляции всё хорошо, а как запускаю программу появляется ошибка Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>


void random1(int arr[5][100]) {
int i,j;
for(i=0; i<5;i++)
{
for(j=0; j<100;j++)
{
arr[i][j]=rand()%100;
printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
} 

void* thread_func1(int arr[5][100]){

int buffer = 1, maxbuffer=0, max=0, minElement=0, maxElement;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<100;j++)
{
if(arr[i][j+1]>arr[i][j])
{ 
buffer++;
max=buffer;
if(maxbuffer<max)
{
maxbuffer = max;
maxElement = arr[i][j+1];
}
}
if(arr[i][j+1]<=arr[i][j])
{
max=buffer;
if(maxbuffer<max)
{ maxbuffer = max;
maxElement = arr[i][j+1];
}
buffer = 1;
}
}
minElement = (maxElement+1)-maxbuffer;

for( i = minElement; i<=maxElement; i++)
{ 

printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
}
} 
}



int main() {

int A[5][100];
int stime;
stime=time(NULL);
srand(stime);
random1(A);
pthread_t k1,k2;
pthread_create(&k1, NULL, (void*)thread_func1,(int*)A);
pthread_join(k1,NULL);
printf("%ld",k1);
exit (0);
}
```

Еще один пример реализации функции thread_func1, но там тоже выходит эта ошибка

```
void* thread_func1(int arr[5][100]){
int start=0, lenght=1, max_start=0, max_lenght=0;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
for(j=0;j<100;j++){
for(int k=j+1;k<100;k++)
{
if(arr[i][j]<arr[i][k])
lenght++;
else{
if(lenght>max_lenght)
max_lenght= lenght, max_start=start;
start = k, lenght = 1;
}
}
}
}
for(i = max_start; i<max_start+max_lenght; i++){
for (j=max_start; i<max_start+max_lenght; i++){
printf("%p", arr[i][j]);}}}
```

Comment: "*При компиляции появляется ошибка Segmentation fault (core dumped)*" - именно при компиляции? не при работе? Т.е. падает компилятор?

Comment: поправила, при запуске программы, при компиляции всё хорошо

Comment: `minElement`/`maxElement` хранят значения, взятые из массива, потенциально рандомные. А у вас они используются для индексации того же массива. `valgrind` в помощь на будущее.

Comment: @extrn а можете подсказать, как это исправить?

Comment: Не использовать содержимое массива в качестве индексов массива, очевидно. Да и алгоритм, даже будь он рабочим, в таком виде не распараллелить. Какой смысл использовать потоки, если работать будет только один из них.

Answer (score 2):

У вас банально выход за границы массива из-за этого и получаете Segmentation Fault.

```
arr[i][j+1]
```

Вы обращаетесь к элементу j+1, при этом максимальный j = 99, ещё плюс один получаем 100. А так как индексация с 0 получается, что обращаемся к элементу, которого нет. Думаю в цикле стоит поменять условие на j < 99

Comment: не помогло, всё так же ошибка